# How to load asynchronously a list of objects from database when a page initializes

Tags: c#, maui

In my project, I followed this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/store-local-data/6-exercise-use-sqlite-asynchronously) to build an async database service called animalServ in this context. However, in the guide it specifies how to load data into a CollectionView, only after the press of a button using an async method:

```
public async void OnGetButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        statusMessage.Text = "";

        List<Animal> animals = await App.animalServ.GetAllAnimals();
        animalList.ItemsSource = animals;
    }
```

I'm avoiding adding such code in the constructor due to asynchronous problems. What would be a proper way to load such data, so that it immediately is visible when opening the page?

Comment: You can call an async method from OnAppearing

Comment: You could also load the data before you instantiate the view and then pass the loaded data to your view through the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I would also suggest using `OnAppearing ()` which will load data immediately **prior** to the Page becoming **visible**. Typically, you want to get the data from database and then assign it to the `CollectionView` when initializing the page. Here's the code snippet below for your refernce:

```
protected override async void OnAppearing() 
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    //Get the data from DB
    UserDB db = await UserDB.Instance;
    List<User> a = await db.GetUserAsync();

    //Assign it to the CollectionView
    UserCollection = new ObservableCollection<User>(a);
    userinfodata.ItemsSource = UserCollection;
}
```